# vue-test-util click trigger on button not firing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vuetify.js, vue-test-utils

I have a Vue component with a button. On a button click, a method is called. I am using Jest for unit test. I expected `.trigger` method from `vue-test-utils` to create a synthetic event on the button, but it does nothing.

I tried calling the method directly on the wrapper by calling `wrapper.vm.addService()` and then using `console.log(wrapper.emitted())`, I indeed can see an event has been triggered. So my question is why the `addServiceBtn.trigger('click')` does not do anything.

The `console.log(wrapper.emitted())` is an empty object. The test result is failed with error message: `Expected spy to have been called, but it was not called.`

**ServiceItem.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-flex xs2>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text id="itemTitle">{{ item.title }}</v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn flat color="green" id="addServiceBtn" @click="this.addService">Add</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-flex>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    title: ''
  }),
  props: {
    item: Object
  },
  methods: {
    addService: function (event) {
      console.log('service item')
      this.$emit('add-service')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**tests.spec.js**

```
import { shallowMount, mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import ServiceItem from '@/components/ServiceItem.vue'
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

describe('ServiceItem.vue', () => {
  it('emits add-service when Add button is clicked', () => {
    const item = {
      title: 'Service'
    }

    const wrapper = mount(ServiceItem, {
      propsData: { item }
    })

    expect(wrapper.find('#addServiceBtn').exists()).toBe(true)
    const addServiceBtn = wrapper.find('#addServiceBtn')

    const spy = spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'addService')

    console.log(wrapper.emitted())
    addServiceBtn.trigger('click')
    expect(wrapper.vm.addService).toBeCalled()

  })
})
```

Comment: Does the test `expect(wrapper.vm.addService).toBeCalled()` work  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got a little mistake in your HTML code. Your bind the `@click` event to your method without any `this`. make it:

```
 <v-btn flat color="green" id="addServiceBtn" @click="addService($event)">Add</v-btn>
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you care to explain why `this.addService` was not working?

Comment: @PayamMesgari Because in vue templates all the properties and variables are implicitly using this, so you don't need to add there when you bind something like this @click="method" vue converts this template to on: { click: _vm.controlChanged } in this case _vm is this

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is another reason why the tests in the original code didn't work: it's the parenthesis in the function call.
I have discovered that the syntax `@click="addService"` will lead to failing tests, while the very similar (and somehow discouraged) syntax `@click="addService()"` will succeed.

Example:

```js
test('Click calls the right function', () => {
    // wrapper is declared before this test and initialized inside the beforeEach
    wrapper.vm.testFunction = jest.fn();
    const $btnDiscard = wrapper.find('.btn-discard');
    $btnDiscard.trigger('click');
    expect(wrapper.vm.testFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

This test was failing with this syntax:

```html
<button class="btn blue-empty-btn btn-discard" @click="testFunction">
  {{ sysDizVal('remove') }}
</button>
```

but worked with this syntax:

```html
<button class="btn blue-empty-btn btn-discard" @click="testFunction()">
  {{ sysDizVal('remove') }}
</button>
```

Comment: Actually after investigating the issue I have posted a similar question, and in the accepted answer you can find some explanation on how to test without adding the parenthesis https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62696939/test-on-function-call-in-vue-template-only-passes-if-the-function-is-called-with

Answer (score 2):

To me it didn work, but failed firing the event when testing with **vue-test-utils** until I added **.native**

```
<v-btn @click.native="addToCart($event)">
      Add
</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 1):

the reason why it didn't work is because `this.addService` in `<template>` u're recommended to remove `this` and say only `@click="addService($event)"` or `@click="addService"` also would work just fine but with no event passed in